# Wordpress - update notification on plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, updates

Currently, if you use Wordpress plugin directory (to host your plugin), you can manage updates and version changes using SVN. Anyone who running that plugin will be notified of version changes and will have option to upgrade it automatically.

How can i add, custom message on plugin page (in dashboard) when there is update available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [answered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90899/12615) the same question at WordPress Answers.

The action hook to add a custom message in the update notice is `in_plugin_update_message-{$folder}/{$file}`, being folder/file the ones from the plugin you want to target:

```
$file   = basename( __FILE__ );
$folder = basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) );
$hook = "in_plugin_update_message-{$folder}/{$file}";
add_action( $hook, 'update_message_wpse_87051', 10, 2 ); 

function update_message_wpse_87051( $plugin_data, $r )
{
    echo 'Hello World';
}
```

And, as you noticed *"Anyone who running that plugin will be notified"*, this only works for active plugins.

PS: clarifying, it only works for an active plugin if the code is included in that plugin. If we use this code in another active plugin, or Must Use plugin, or in the theme `functions.php`, then the message will be displayed regardless of the target plugin being active or not.

Comment: is this code working in 2022?

Comment: @user9437856, did you try it?

Comment: Yes but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pluginUpdateMessaage($data, $response){
  
printf(
        '<div class="update-message"><p><strong>%s</strong></p></div>',
        __( 'Version 2.3.4 is a recommended update message', 'text-domain' )
    );
}

add_action('in_plugin_update_message-your-plugin/your-plugin.php','pluginUpdateMessage',10,2);
```

Comment: Could you explain us whats happening in this code and how it solves the problem?

Comment: If the updates are available in that plugin there is message shows in plugins section. we can use this action to show change update message for your plugin in list of installed plugins.

Comment: This code is available in many blog pages but I could not find where to put it exactly? inside the file your-plugin.php and add it to where?

Comment: You can add it to functions.php or use code snippets plugin